# Function 'is not defined' when it is

Tags: javascript, html, raphael, modernizr

I have drawn a map in Inkscape, saved it as SVG and used http://readysetraphael.com/ to convert it to Raphial.
I put this generated code into a function called `drawMap` and I have saved this in js/map.js

js/map.js:

```
function drawMap(){
 var map = Raphael('map', '100mm', '100mm');
 var layer4 = map.set();
 var path3041 = map.path("m 106.15571,153.07817 -1.64315,13.74999 4.60661,10.36488 6.04618,9.21323 9.21323,3.16705 6.04618,6.04618 8.34949,8.06157 77.4487,1.72748 3.45496,-48.79108 z");
 path3041.attr({id: 'path3041',parent: 'layer4',opacity: '0.98999999',fill: '#ffb380',stroke: '#000000',"stroke-width": '3',"stroke-linecap": 'butt',"stroke-linejoin": 'miter',"stroke-miterlimit": '4',"stroke-opacity": '1',"stroke-dasharray": 'none'}).data('id', 'path3041');
 layer4.attr({'id': 'layer4','name': 'layer4'});

 //etc, more lines than stackoverflow will let me add

var mapGroups = [layer4,layer5,layer19,layer20,layer21,layer22,layer23,layer24,layer25,layer26,layer6,layer7,layer8,layer9,layer10,layer1,layer3,layer11,layer12,layer13,layer14,layer15,layer16,layer17,layer18,layer27,layer28,layer29,layer30,layer31,layer32,layer33,layer34,layer35,layer36,layer37,layer38,layer39,layer40,layer41,layer42,layer43,layer44,layer45];
}
```

I then put `raphael-min.js` and into the 'js' folder.

When I called `drawMap()`  firebug said:

> "drawMap is not defined"

I added the containts of map.js into the html file but I recived the error "Raphial is not defined".

I assumed this was as raphial was being called before `raphial-min.js` had loaded so I used Modernizer to load `raphial-min.js` and `map.ja` before calling `drawMap()` but now I get the error:

> "drawMap is not defined"

Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Risk</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://modernizr.com/downloads/modernizr.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="map">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        drawMap()
        Modernizr.load({
            load: 'js/raphael-min.js',
            load: 'js/map.js',
            complete: drawMap()
        })
    </script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several issues with the Modernizr implementation.

1. In the `complete` property, you should not be calling `drawMap`, just referring to it and since it's not loaded yet, you have to refer to it in an anonymous inline function.
2. You should not be calling `drawMap()` before loading it.
3. In the Modernizr.load() syntax, javascript doesn't let you use multiple `load` properties on the same object.

So this:

```
drawMap();
Modernizr.load({
    load: 'js/raphael-min.js',
    load: 'js/map.js',
    complete: drawMap()
})
```

should be this:

```
Modernizr.load({
    load: ['js/raphael-min.js', 'js/map.js'],
    complete: function() {drawMap();}
})
```

Also, I don't know why you're dynamically loading these.  It probably isn't necessary.  you could just do this:

```
<script src="js/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="js/map.js"></script>
<script>
drawMap();
</script>
```

Comment: @amnotiam - I've added the other issue.

Comment: I have made the changes, but the map is still not displayed and firebug sais "If <script> tags have a "type" attribute, it should equal "text/javascript" or "application/javascript". Also scripts must be parsable (syntactically correct)."

Comment: @jfriend00: Regarding the *"should be this:"* code block, you're still trying to reference `drawMap`. Unless I'm misunderstanding the question, I think `drawMap` is in one of the two files being loaded, so it wouldn't be available when `Modernizr.load` is called.

Comment: @gilbertbw - which version that I posted did you try?  I fixed a mistake with the quote marks the `<script>` tag version.

Comment: @amnotiam - You are correct.  I moved it into an anonymous function.

Comment: I have tryed the last suggestion but get the `drawMap is not defined` error, with the top suggestion I get `Modernizr.load is not a function` on line 13

Comment: @gilbertbw - then you probably haven't loaded the Modernizr library first.  As I said in my second example, I don't know why you're using dynamic loading in the first place.  Simple `<script>` tags should work.

Comment: When using simple `<script>` tags I get `drawMap is not defined` I have got modenized loaded `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://modernizr.com/downloads/modernizr.js"></script>`, the error is on the line `compleate: function() {drawMap();}`

Comment: @gilbertbw - I redid the modernizr implementation above after reading its doc for loading multiple scripts.  I can't really help any further without you showing us the actual web page that doesn't work.  I honestly don't know exactly what code you've tried so can't comment on what isn't working in it.  If drawMap is not defined, then you either haven't successfully loaded the script that contains it or it's not available in the proper javascript scope.  Without seeing the actual implementation, I can't tell you which it is or whether there's some other error stopping things before that.

Comment: @gilbertbw - unless you have a specific reason for dynamic script loading, just use the `<script>` tag version which is a lot simpler.

Comment: I was using `src="js/map.js"` but my javascript files are in a file called `javascripts` It works using the simple `<script>` method, Thankyou for your help

Answer (score 1):

`drawMap` is being called before the script file is loaded.

Comment: But i'm using modernizer to load the script and only call 'drawMap' when loading is compleate

Comment: @gilbertbw - i see a call to draw map before `Modernizer`.